# How do I add a blog_id prefix to article controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I have a Shopify rails app and in my Articles controller I'm not sure how to add a `"prefix_option"` like it's asking for in the exception catcher. I'm a beginner rails developer so it's very possible I'm missing something obvious. This is all I have in the controller at the moment:

```
class ArticleController < ApplicationController

around_filter :shopify_session

  def show
     @article = ShopifyAPI::Article.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: blog_id prefix_option is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Articles are nested under Blogs, so you need to specify the id of the blog under which you're looking.

This should work: `ShopifyAPI::Article.find(params[:id], :params => {:blog_id => blog_id})`

N.B: The Shopify API's ruby wrapper is based on ActiveResource, so a lot of questions can be answered by looking at AR's docs.

Specs for the find method are here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-c-find

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had a similar string in place where the last "blog_id" (the 'value' in the 'key => value pair'? rails learning...) was :blog_id as was passed in from my action link in the view. When I use yours it says that 'blog_id' is an undefined local variable. 

Further, I nested my articles resource in a blog resource 'do' and the url string LOOKS like I would expect from the API documentation (/blog/b_id/article/a_id but ) but it still says I'm missing the blog_id prefix. Any other suggestion? Thanks.